# HttpSessionState not available during SignalR.PersistentConnection.OnConnected event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using SignalR for pushing messages from an ASP.NET MVC server to web clients.

I want to store the connection Id of the current client when a new connection from a client has been accepted, so that when I want to send data to this specific client, I can retrieve its connection Id from the Session and send it the message.

However, in the OnConnected event handler, the session is null. As a result, my code throws a null reference exception when I try to put the connectionId in the session.

Here's the code snippet.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace TestSignalR
{
    public class SignalRServerListener : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected(
                                          IRequest request, 
                                          string connectionId)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.
             Print("Connection request received and accepted from 
             client with connection Id {0}", connectionId);

            HttpContext.Current.Session["connectionId"] = connectionId;

            return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the clients like below

```
class MyConnections
{
    private static List<String> _MyClients = new List<String>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        _MyClients.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        _MyClients.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public static bool IsConnected(string cid)
    {
        return _MyClients.Contains(cid);
    }
}
```

> Now, when the server wants to send data to one of those clients, how
>   should the server know which connection Id should be used in the
>   Context.Connection.Send(connectionId, message)?

```
Context.DefaultSignal
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and this article, which I read while waiting for an answer (http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2013/03/24/Real-time-User-Notification-and-Session-Management-with-SignalR-Part-2.aspx) seem to suggest that we have to keep track of connection Id's ourselves.

But if this is an application-wide list (since it is static), how can I be sure if a certain connection Id belongs to the current HttpRequest/client?

Comment: Current request is sure to be captured in `OnConnected` override and same connection will be captured again while disconnected.

Comment: I think we are not able to understand each other very well. Let's assume that I have 3 clients connected to the server. In that case, your List<string> will have 3 connection Id's. Now, when the server wants to send data to one of those clients, how should the server know which connection Id should be used in the Context.Connection.Send(`connectionId`, message)?

Comment: You can use `Context.ConnectionId`

Comment: I don't see a property called `ConnectionId` on the `Context` object returned by `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<SignalRServerListener>()` but I tried using the `DefaultSignal` property of the `Context` object and it worked. So, thank you. Your post helped me solve my problem. Green chekie to you. :-)